# Formula for the square root of a symetric, positive definite 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have heard there is a unique real solution for the square root of symmetric, positive definite matrices. Is there a simple formula to calculate it in the 2x2 case?

$\Sigma^{0.5} = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_{11} & v_{12} \\
    v_{12} & v_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}^{0.5}$

I know the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix) for the general case, yet I want to find a formula which gets me only the true solution, not 4 potential ones.

Comment: The Wiki link actually only says unique *positive definite* square root for a positive definite matrix. That doesn't rule out, on the face of it, another square root which isn't positive definite.

Comment: In fact the 2 by 2 identity matrix is positive definite, since it goes with $x^2+y^2.$ But the matrix with $0$ as diagonal entries and $1$ off diagonal has square the identity. This other square root (other than identity) goes with $2xy$ so isn't positive definite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you guarantee that $\Sigma$ is positive definite, then if you choose plus signs in both $s$ and $t$ in Wikipedia formula, you will get a positive definite matrix.

In other words:
$$
s=\sqrt{v_{11}v_{22}-v_{12}^2}\qquad t=\sqrt{v_{11}+v_{22}+2s}\\
\sqrt{\Sigma} = \frac1t(\Sigma+sI)
$$

You can easily see that:
$$
u^T\sqrt{\Sigma}u=\frac1t(u^T\Sigma u+su^2).
$$
is always positive if $u^T\Sigma u$ is positive.